# Round the number of my y axis in plot.zoo r

Tags: r

Good morning, i have the next code:

```
plot.zoo(ResultadosLP, plot.type="m", ylab = c("Spread", "Mid_Rqs", "L_Rqs",                                          "Mid_QP","Ef_Spread","Mid_Res",                                               "L_Res", "IRC"), cex.axis=0.65,xlab = "Fecha(periodicidad mensual)"
```

I want to round the numbers of my axis `y` because I got 4 digits, and I need only one digit in the plot, how can I do that?
Note: it is a multiplot, and if you could give me other advice to solve the problem of size, I appreciate so much that. I tried **cex.axis**, but I can't keep going because is too small.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `signif()` on the variables in `ResultadosLP` you're plotting on the y-axis before you plot it. You can set the argument `digits = 2`